# How do I get the first half and second half depending on the epoch time('attempt_updated_at' column)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, epoch

So, I want to find out the 'Avg. difficulty level in first vs. second half of each session', I cannot find a proper way to solve this.
I have the divide the session into 2 halves using the epoch time and then find the Avg difficulty level.

```
session_id  question_difficulty     attempt_updated_at
5c822af21c1fba22            2   1557470128000
5c822af21c1fba22            3   1557469685000
5c822af21c1fba22            4   1557470079000
5c822af21c1fba22            5   1557472999000
5c822af21c1fba22            3   1557474145000
5c822af21c1fba22            3   1557474441000
5c822af21c1fba22            4   1557474299000
5c822af21c1fba22            4   1557474738000
5c822af21c1fba22            3   1557475430000
5c822af21c1fba22            4   1557476960000
5c822af21c1fba22            5   1557477458000
5c822af21c1fba22            2   1557478118000
5c822af21c1fba22            5   1557482556000
5c822af21c1fba22            4   1557482809000
5c822af21c1fba22            5   1557482886000
5c822af21c1fba22            5   1557484232000
```

I am working on python pandas(Jupter Notebook).

Code wise I don't know where to start. (Noobie Alert)

I expect the output like:

session_id  first-half-difficulty second-half-difficulty

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IIUC, you could use [`pandas.qcut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.qcut.html) to cut epochs into 2 equally sized bins (first half / second half). Then use [`groupby.mean`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.mean.html):

```
df.groupby(['session_id', pd.qcut(df.attempt_updated_at, q=2)])['question_difficulty'].mean()
```

[out]

```
session_id        attempt_updated_at                  
5c822af21c1fba22  (1557469684999.999, 1557475084000.0]    3.500
                  (1557475084000.0, 1557484232000.0]      4.125
Name: question_difficulty, dtype: float64
```

---

Alternatively, depending on how you define 'first half' / 'second half', you may require [`pandas.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.cut.html) instead, with `bins=2` argument *(in this case the time bins will be equally spaced as opposed to equally sized as per `qcut` above)*:

```
df.groupby(['session_id', pd.cut(df.attempt_updated_at, bins=2)])['question_difficulty'].mean()
```

[out]

```
session_id        attempt_updated_at                
5c822af21c1fba22  (1557469670453.0, 1557476958500.0]    3.444444
                  (1557476958500.0, 1557484232000.0]    4.285714
Name: question_difficulty, dtype: float64
```

---

#### Update

To calculate different time buckets for unique session_id, you may first have to group by `session_id` ; run the above method over each group ; then finally, [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) the results. Here is an example using list comprehension:

```
groups_session_id = df.groupby('session_id')

pd.concat([g.groupby(['session_id', pd.cut(g['attempt_updated_at'], bins=2).astype(str)])
           ['question_difficulty'].mean() for _, g in groups_session_id])
```

---

#### Update 2

To add these average values back into your original `DataFrame`, you can use [`DataFrame.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
df_avg_question_difficulty = pd.concat([g.groupby(['session_id', pd.cut(g['attempt_updated_at'], bins=2, labels = [1, 2]).astype(str)])
                                        ['question_difficulty'].mean().unstack(1) for _, g in groups_session_id])

df = df.merge(df_avg_question_difficulty, left_on='session_id', right_index=True)
```

Comment: Thank you. It does work but when i try with 10 different session_id's the output is in shambles.

Comment: @RedDragon I updated my answer, i believe if you need to calculate different time buckets for each session_id, you may need nested `groupby`

Comment: Is there a way to print like this {session_id, mean1 , mean2 } ?

Comment: You could add `labels` argument to the `pd.cut` method, and [`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) level 1 index from your groupby object. so... `pd.concat([g.groupby(['session_id', pd.cut(g['attempt_updated_at'], bins=2, labels = [1, 2]).astype(str)])['question_difficulty'].mean().unstack(1) for _, g in groups_session_id])`

Comment: Is there a way to save the columns in the dataframe?

Comment: hey @RedDragon . Could you explain a bit more? What columns are you looking to save and into which dataframe?

Comment: Here, we are  getting back session_id, mean1 , mean2 as output. Is there a way to save the columns (mean1,mean2) in my dataframe?

Comment: I've updated the answer, using `merge`... let me know if this is what you mean